# freebsd echo binary content output

Tags: echo, freebsd, binary-data

I'm reading interesting book [John Ericson's hacking book]

So in that book, he writes binary content to file with "echo -ne" command. But in freeBSD no -e option. Tried to look to another commands, but with no success. 
Any advice?
Thanx

Comment: Have you tried to use `printf` instead?

Comment: There is /bin/echo, but also an echo built-in to sh which does -e. you cannot mix -e and -n, but use `\c` at the end to do same as -n.

Comment: Yes, @jubobs, I tried printf, but with no success.

Comment: Tried to change shell, result is the same, @meuth

Comment: @Kamil What do you mean by "with no success"? `printf` is more portable than `echo`. It doesn't require the `-e` flag to recognise escaped characters, and it doesn't require the `-n` flag, because it prints no trailing newline character.

Comment: printf "\x31" > shellcode.bin
$ hexdump -C shellcode.bin
00000000  78 33 31                                          |x31|

Comment: $ printf "0x31" > shellcode.bin
$ hexdump -C shellcode.bin
00000000  30 78 33 31                                       |0x31|

Comment: Maybe, I write not in suspected fomat, but it's not as expected. Could you please send me sample

Comment: bsd printf and echo -e only accept `\061` octal escapes.

Comment: Try `printf "%X" "31"`.

Comment: Something like that @Jubobs, but I have huge string of HEX which has to be written in file, exactly in that format

Comment: Sounds ferociously about octals, why would bsd printf/echo operate with octals, not with binary and hex?

Comment: Are you required to use something that is in the base system? You could install gnu coreutils from the ports collection ports/sysutils/coreutils. It's installed as gecho